# hide/show of a div on selection of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html code

```
<div class="wrapper"> <strong>Space portion</strong>

<br />
<input type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="RJ" />Space 1
<br />
<input type="radio" name="rdSpace" value="SM" />Space 2
<br />
<br />
</div>
<div class="wrapper"> <strong> Template</strong>

<br />
<input type="radio" name="rdTemplate" value="uploadTemplate" />Upload your own file
<label class="cabinet">
    <input style="margin-left:10px;" type="file" name="user_upload_template"
    class="uploader" id="file">
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="rdTemplate" value="preExisting" />Choose below
    <div id="RJ" class="tempDisp">Div 1 Preview</div>
    <div id="SM" class="tempDisp">Div 2 Preview</div>
```

this is jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div.tempDisp").hide();
$('[id="' + $(":radio:checked").val() + '"]').show();
$('input[name="rdSpace"]:radio,input[name="rdTemplate"]').click(function () {
    $("div.tempDisp").fadeOut('slow');
    $('[id="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

the purpose of jquery code is to display "Div 1 Preview" on selection of "Space 1" radio and to display "Div 2 Preview" on selection of "Space 2" radio.. till now it is working fine

now I tried to add the functionality of hiding "Div 1 Preview" and "Div 2 Preview" on selection of "Upload your own file" radio.. I got success and on selection of said button those are hiding.. but the problem is that they are not displayed back when I click back "Choose below" radio.. why??

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bTM66/

Comment: you haven't told them to show

Comment: @popnoodles ohh this is the case.. how can I tell then??

Comment: When the user clicks any input in that scope there, check the value of rdTemplate. If it's preExisting, show the correct div as you are doing else show none. You need to not use `$('[id="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');` because that procedure is applied to all radio buttons so need to use `$('[id="' + $('input[name="rdSpace"]:checked').val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');` instead

Comment: @popnoodles not working.. cn u plz update fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.tempDisp").hide();
    $('[id="' + $(":radio:checked").val() + '"]').show();
    $('input[name="rdSpace"]:radio,input[name="rdTemplate"]').change(function () {
        $("div.tempDisp").fadeOut('slow');
        if ($(this).val() === "preExisting") {
            $(":radio:checked:first").change();
        } else {
            if(!$('input[value="uploadTemplate"]').is(':checked')){
            $('[id="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
          }
        }
    });
});
```

See **[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFbNZ/2/)**

Comment: but there is one problem... when "Upload your own file" is selected and "Space 1" or "Space 2" is toggled it is displaying the "Div 1 Preview" or "Div 2 Preview" whatever is applicable.. it shall not happen.. how to prevent this??

Comment: The only issue I see with this is that, unlike how you (@aks) write the code, this depends on the radios being in a specific order. `$(":radio:checked:first").change();`. Just so you're aware.

Answer (score 2):

So to get one or none of the two divs showing depending on the two separate values.

The click event is bound to both sets of radio buttons, so you can't use `$(this)` to get the value of the checked one to pick an ID to show, you need to specify which radio button selection it's from by its name.

You also need to check which of the other selection (browser/pick) is checked and show or not show.

And use on change instead of click so you don't get unnecessary fadeout/fadein.

And I would add `style="display:none"` to the divs .tempDisp so they are already hidden on load without js.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bTM66/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[name="rdSpace"]:radio,input[name="rdTemplate"]').on('change', function () {
        $("div.tempDisp").fadeOut('slow');
        if ($('input[name="rdTemplate"]:checked').val()=='preExisting'){
            $('[id="' + $('input[name="rdSpace"]:checked').val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    })
});
```

Set this one to checked so the decision to show can be made on the user changing the first selection.

```
<input type="radio" name="rdTemplate" value="preExisting" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: the problem now is... that when page is loaded the divs are invisible and they are activated only when I click on "Choose below".. prior to clicking "Choose below" if I click on "Space 1" or "Space 2 " nothing is happening...

Comment: Yes you need both of the two options to make the decision. If you set the default one to checked="checked" in the HTML that will show you what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/bTM66/7/

Comment: but again a problem.. when page is loaded it is refreshing that block "Preview" 4 times... why is that??

Comment: drop trigger change. Not entirely possible to see how it works outside of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

**what your code is doing..**

`$('input[name="rdSpace"]:radio,input[name="rdTemplate"]').click(function () {` == when clicked, on radio with given selector

`$("div.tempDisp").fadeOut('slow');` == div with class tempDisp fade out slow

`$('[id="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');` == the div with id (selected radio val) show

**the problem**

on click `Upload your own file` the current value is `uploadTemplate` and jquery will not be able to find div with `id = uploadTemplate` . so nothing happens.

onclick  `Choose below` same thing.. current value is `preExisting` and again it will not find div with `id=preExisting`. so nothing happens again

**the work around**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("div.tempDisp").hide();
   $('[id="' + $(":radio:checked").val() + '"]').show();
   $('input[name="rdSpace"]:radio,input[name="rdTemplate"]').click(function () {
      $("div.tempDisp").fadeOut('slow');
      $('[id="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
      if($(this).val()=="preExisting"){ //here check if value is preExistig
         $('#'+ $('input[name="rdSpace"]:checked').val()).fadeIn('slow');
         //$('#RJ,#SM').fadeIn('slow');  //if yes show the div you wanted which is RJ,SM
      }
   });
});
```

**update**

replace

```
  $('#RJ,#SM').fadeIn('slow');
```

with

```
 $('#'+ $('input[name="rdSpace"]:checked').val()).fadeIn('slow');
```

[updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/bTM66/9/)

Comment: it is displaying both divs on selection of "Choose Below" it shall take into account though above selection also.. Space 1 or Space 2